# OrientDB 3 sql script error

Tags: orientdb

I'am migrating from ODB 2.2.29 to 3.0.1 and I find an error that I have not been able to understand.
I have a class called 'EdgeAttrib'. The class does not exist yet in the DB. 
Now consider this code:

```
let exist = select from (select expand(classes) from metadata:schema) where name = 'EdgeAttrib';
if ($exist.size()>0) {
     delete vertex EdgeAttrib;
     drop class EdgeAttrib;
}
```

work well in 2.2.29 and fail in 3.0.1. Even more, the same code for other class work fine. 
When I run it, it throw:

```
 com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class not found: EdgeAttrib DB name="Test"
```

That happend when try to execute the "delete vertex" line, but the class does not exist so it should never run that line.
I run this code in the ODB Studio.

Comment: Hi, could you open an issue on github.com? Thx

Answer (score 0):

The fix was added in version 3.0.3.